# Can I translte a Wordpress PO file online?

Tags: wpf, themes, translation, po

Hi 
Can I just translate my theme po file online and save it our do i have to compile it to work?
Do you know how i mean?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your .po file needs to be compiled into a .mo file for it to be understood. Use a program like Poedit to compile your .po file into a .mo file (upon saving).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile your .po files you can do it online on http://kcy.me/cc1k

Answer (score 0):

since the link from @Isra is dead, here's an awesome online po to mo converter:

http://po2mo.net/